Problem to get the correct URL on odoo 15 webpage
I'm having problems to get the correct parameter values when accessing a webpage on my Odoo server. the URL came with only only one parameter ID,  the first time the correct value get is get with request.params.get() but next time when I change de id value it still come with the previous old id.
First time I try  https://adm.xxx/website_reference_form?id=299, it works well.
Next time I try https://adm.xxx/website_reference_form?id=254 and here the previous 299 id is get.
this is what I see inside the webpage.

when ID is 254.
I can try different IDs, first works well, next IDs don't.
Why Odoo is getting the incorrect URL, Nginx problem?

Please provide your code (xml and py controller)...

Hi Ahrimann: I did not create an specific controller for the page, using the default one and the web form controller to create the record on the model i need. How can i upload the xml file?
